# jQuery. Pass a variable from a function to an .each inside

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I want to pass a variable, either '1' or '2' and run a function depending on available size. How can i ensure that the var can get pass through another function? Thanks!

```
$(function() {
    function newFunc(varNum){
        $('.listing__item .item__details').each(function() {
            var ul = $('ul.item__authors', this);
            var authors = $('.item__authors-info', this);
            if(ul.children('li.author').size() <= varNum) return;

            var hiddenElements = ul.children('li:gt(varNum)', this).hide(),
                showCaption = '+ ' + hiddenElements.size() + ' others';

            authors.append($('<span class="other-authors">' + showCaption + '</span>'));
        });
    }       
    newFunc('1');
});
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Inner functions can always access variables from outer functions, unless they declare a local variable with the same name.

Comment: The only problem I see is `'li:gt(varNum)'`. Variables aren't evaluated inside strings.

Comment: Thanks, but if I run it without being inside newFunc it works fine if I put '1' instead of varNum.. But i need to be able to run newFunc depending on a few things, so need to pass a number to it

Comment: no @Barmar tell to you so you need use varNum as variable not as string

Comment: `ul.children()` only takes one argument. Why are you passing `this` as the second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var hiddenElements = ul.children('li:gt(' + varNum + ')').hide,
```

You have to use string concatenation to substitute the value of a variable into the selector string. And `.children()` only takes one argument, there's no need ot pass `this` (you already used `this` when setting `ul`).